# Copy formula in range of cells to different worksheet when option selected in drop down list

Tags: excel, eventtrigger, vba

I have 2 drop-down lists working fine together. I need the 2nd one to copy a range of cells formulas over from one sheet to current in predefined cells. (All work sheets and list are in the same workbook.)  Currently trying with a macro. How can I trigger a macro once an option is selected in a drop down menus?

Comment: Look into the [Worksheet_Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)

Comment: Use `OptionButton1.Value = True` or `OptionButton2.Value = False` Where those values are Boolean